# Using javascript and Jquery widgets in Visual Web Part. Is it posible?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I am trying to build a Visual Web Part in Visual Studio for Sharepoint Foundation and I am wondering if I can use Javascript for some functions and jquery widgets to create a listbox? I have tried but I got errors.

```
var lblEmtyList = '';

    function getAccordion(idx, count, label, close, expand) {
        var html = (close) ? '</ul></div></div></div>' : '';
        var classExpand = (expand) ? ' in' : '';
        html += '<div class="panel panel-default r9form-panel">' +
              '<div class="panel-heading r9form-panel-heading" id="r9HeadPanelRel' + idx + '" role="tab">' +
              '<span class="badge" id="r9PanelBadge' + idx + '">' + count + '</span> ' +
              '<a aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="r9PanelRel' + idx + '" href="#r9PanelRel' + idx + '" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent-not="#accordion">' + label + '</a>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="panel-collapse collapse' + classExpand + '" id="r9PanelRel' + idx + '" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="r9HeadPanelRel' + idx + '">' +
              '<div class="panel-body r9list-panel-body">' +
              '<ul class="list-group panel-heading-list-group r9form-list-group" id="r9PanelList' + idx + '">';
        return html;
    }

    function getToDoList(expand) {
        if (arguments.length < 1) expand = false;
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'get',
            //'url': 'http://w2k12sp01/rmtplus_v50/Json.ashx'
            'url': '/rmtplus_v50/Json.ashx'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var totalItems = 0, countItems = 0, listHtml = '<li class="list-group-item">' + lblEmtyList + '</li>';
            if (data && data.items && data.items.length > 0) {
                var items = data.items;
                var classes = data.classes; // classes": [{"CLAS_Name": "Dokument", "total": "3", ... }]
                var iClass = 0; className = classes[0].CLAS_Name;
                totalItems = data.total;
                countItems = items.length;
                listHtml = getAccordion(0, classes[iClass].total, className, false, expand);
                $.each(items, function (i) {
                    if (items[i].CLAS_Name != className && classes.length > iClass + 1) {
                        className = classes[++iClass].CLAS_Name;
                        listHtml += getAccordion(iClass, classes[iClass].total, className, true, expand);
                    }
                    listHtml += '<li class="list-group-item">'
                    listHtml += '<span class="r9sub-text">' + items[i].ACTN_AddedWhen + ' ' + items[i].CATE_Name + ' ' + items[i].MREC_NaturalId + '</span> ';
                    listHtml += '<p><a href="javascript:showInDetails(\'Form.aspx?id=' + items[i].MREC_Id + '&todo=' + items[i].ACTN_ACTP_Id + '\')">' + items[i].ACTP_Label + ': ' + items[i].MREC_Name + '</a>';
                    if (items[i].Info.length > 0) listHtml += ' <a class="btn btn-xs" tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<button type=\'button\' class=\'close\' onclick=\'$(this).closest(&quot;div.popover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);\' aria-hidden=\'true\'>&times;</button><div>' + items[i].Info.replace(/\r/g, '</div><div>').replace(/\n/g, '') + '</div>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>';
                    listHtml += '</p></li>';
                });
                listHtml += '</ul></div></div></div>';
            }
            $("#todoTotal").text(totalItems);
            $("#todoListGroup").html(listHtml);
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ placement: 'auto', html: true, title: lblState });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getToDoList(true); 
    });
```

Comment: You can use JS. How did you use? show code and error.

Comment: I wrote code in ASP.Web Application and it worked there.  Now I am tryng to take that code and past it in Visual Web Part.

Comment: Two document ready, why? what's your console error?

Comment: I forgot to remove second document.ready, I was just trying something.Now I got just an empty page,it shows nothong. I think it is because of Jquery widgets and  references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use JavaScript and JQuery in a Visual Web part. The main problem is to deploy, store and reference .js files properly.
You can deploy/store them at two possible locations:

- in _layouts
- in a SharePoint Library

In both cases, simply add a reference at the top of the .ascx file.

Answer (score 2):

Two general coding comments:

1. Avoid using the jQuery shortcut "$" on SharePoint pages
   It could already be in use by other SharePoint functionality. Please use "jQuery" instead.
2. Avoid "jQuery(document).ready" usage
   Instead build your logic inside a function (e.g. function MyRunOnStart() {...}) and add this using

   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('myRunOnStart');

Question:
Which SharePoint Foundation version?

And additionally: why do you use two document.ready calls? Especiall when you reload the page by changing the location?

HTH
Rainer

Comment: I forgot to remove second document.ready, I was just trying something